# Is it possible to extend or implement a Cursor?

Tags: android, cursor

I am in a situation where I will probably need to manipulate two separate `Cursor` objects. I was hoping there was someway to create our own Cursor by combining two separate ones. But I am not sure if it is even allowed. Read somewhere you can't, but I wanted to devote a specific question to that so it is at least given some attention for others who have a similar situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was hoping there was someway to create our own Cursor by combining two separate ones

Have you tried `MergeCursor`? Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MergeCursor.html):

> A convience class that lets you present an array of Cursors as a single linear Cursor. The schema of the cursors presented is entirely up to the creator of the MergeCursor, and may be different if that is desired. Calls to getColumns, getColumnIndex, etc will return the value for the row that the MergeCursor is currently pointing at.

Also, if your objective is to display both `Cursors` in some form of `AdapterView`, you could use [my `MergeAdapter`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) and concatenate things at the `Adapter` level

Comment: Oooo, no I did not try that because I had no idea it existed. I tried searching for something but there isn't much discussion on it. Thanks to you, thats exactly what I was looking for! I was going to create my own using `CursorWrapper`, but this works much better :) thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, I am looking at the doc, but it doesn't explain whether `getCount` would get the count of all the cursors, the array holding the cursors, etc. Am I to assume it is the overall length of all the cursors added? Am I also to assume that it would also go through each index in the cursor array in order, going through each individual cursor in order without any extra work from me? Just wanted to make sure as I never used it. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @Andy: "Am I to assume it is the overall length..." -- yes, as you can see from the source code: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/database/MergeCursor.java "Am I to assume that it would also go through each index in the cursor..." -- if by "index" you mean "position", then yes (again, use the source).

Answer (score 1):

Even if you found a solution for your concrete use case, i would still like to answer your main question.

Yes it's possible to implement your own cursors.

[Cursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) is a public interface and can be implemented by everybody.

It has, however, a large amount of methods that need to be implemented.

Using [AbstractCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/AbstractCursor.html) or [AbstractWindowedCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/AbstractWindowedCursor.html) as base class can help to reduce the overhead.

The available concrete implementations can be extended, too.

`CrossProcessCursor, CrossProcessCursorWrapper, CursorWrapper, MatrixCursor, MergeCursor, MockCursor, SQLiteCursor`

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that too, for `AbstractCursor`. But how to I get the values inside of two Cursors into a single Cursor with your method? I am looking at AbstractCursor, but I do not see where the elements go. I see all the methods that it uses, but nothing that housing the elements.